# nodejs X DevApi add return id

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have read in the mysql 8 docs that a collection.add operation returns the id of the document added i the result. But I have seen no example of how to get that returned id.

I tried the following. The document is inserted but no clue about the returned result

```
     mysqlx
.getSession(mysqlxOptions)
.then(function (session) {
  var db = session.getSchema('oa4');
  // Use the collection 'my_collection'
  var myColl = db.getCollection('order_items');
  return myColl;
})
.then(function (myColl) {
  // Insert documents
  return Promise
    .all([
        myColl.add(req.body).execute()
    ])
})
.then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
  res.send(result);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.log(err);
});
```

What is the right way to get the result and pass it on?

Comment: MySQL 8.0 document store is pretty much extra overhead as it is simulated NoSQL.. Did you know MySQL 8.0 is basically running a "NoSQL" interface on top off the standard SQL engine... Check it you would see there is a `order_items` table in your database with a one column which is a JSON datatype.

Answer (score 1):

The `execute()` method returns a `Promise` that resolves to a [`Result`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-Result.html) instance, which in turn provides a `getGeneratedIds()` method that in the case of [`Collection.add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-CollectionAdd.html) contains an list of the `_id`s that have been auto-generated by the server for any inserted document that does not have one already.

```
Promise.all([myColl.add(req.body).execute()])
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log(results[0].getGeneratedIds()[0]);
  })
```

In this case, and assuming `req.body` is itself a single document, if it contains an `_id` property, its value will be effectively used as the identifier, and the server will not auto-generate one, and as such, it will not be available in the list returned by `getGeneratedIds()`.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead maintainer of the X DevAPI Node.js connector for MySQL.